# How to use deployment.yaml variables inside siddhi app?

Tags: deployment, wso2, configuration-files, siddhi

In siddhi email documentation it says that the account configurations can be done on the deployment file. But there is no information about how to use those variables and where the deployment yaml should be or which deployment file should be. 
https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-email/api/1.0.2/

So I have tried creating a deployment file inside the conf/PROFILE/ 
and also tried adding the fields in all the deployment.yaml files.
But I haven't found a way to use inside the siddhi app.

Answer (score 1):

The following element should be added to /conf/profile/deployment.yaml file to set the system properties,

```
siddhi:
  extensions:
    - extension:
        name: email
        namespace: sink
        properties:
          host: 0.0.0.0
          port: 5511
```

Please see below, [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Configuring+System+Parameters+for+Siddhi+Extensions) for further information.

Comment: Please include an actual example or explanation in your answer, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. Updated!